# How to remove broken connection object from connection pool? using c3p0

Tags: java, spring, jpa, c3p0

How to remove broken connection object from connection pool? using c3p0

In my application when the database communication failure, it shows exception. After getting database connection immediately send any database request i am getting same exception. Any request after 30 seconds of getting database connection it works normally. so how can i remove broken connection object?

my connection properties are:-

```
url=jdbc:mysql://db_host:db_port/db_name
driverClassName=db_driver_class_name
username=root
password=password
hibernate.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
initialPoolSize=5
minPoolSize=5
maxPoolSize=20
checkoutTimeout=1000
maxStatements=20
acquireRetryAttempts=1
acquireRetryDelay=10
maxIdleTime=1
acquireIncrement=0
maxConnectionAge=1
```

Answer (score 0):

c3p0 can test the connection in several ways:

- on check out
- on check in
- periodically

the configuration is described here: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

be aware that connection testings adds some overhead depending how much work you do with a acquired connection.

Answer (score 0):

include following parameters in your config

```
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time">6</prop>
   <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time_excess_connection">4</prop>
   <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_connection_test_period">600</prop>
   <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.test_connection_on_checkout">true</prop>
   <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferred_test_query">SELECT 1;</prop>
```

Hope this work for you